# Javascript if statement won't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I've been building this site that will get run an API depending on the search parameters. I used an if statement to determine the dropdown value. But for some reason the if statment doesn't run. Is there something I am doing wrong please? Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="bestbuysearch">
<select name="selection" onchange="setvalue()">
<option value="default">Select Category(Optional)</option>
<option value="abcat0100000">TV & Home Theater</option>
<option value="abcat0207000">Musical Instruments</option>
<option value="abcat0300000">Car, Marine & GPS</option>
<option value="abcat0400000">Cameras & Camcorders</option>
<option value="abcat0500000">Computers & Tablets</option>
<option value="abcat0600000">Movies & Music</option>
<option value="abcat0700000">Video Games</option>
<option value="abcat0800000">Mobile Phones</option>
<option value="abcat0900000">Appliances</option>
<option value="pcmcat142300050026">Outlet Center</option>
<option value="pcmcat242800050021">Health, Fitness & Sports</option>
<option value="pcmcat245100050028">Office</option>
<option value="pcmcat248700050021">Home</option>

</select>
<input type='text' id="item" placeholder='Search Here!' style='margin-top: 10px' size="70" maxlength=150 width="100px" />       
<input type='submit' value="Search" onclick="getstring(document.getElementById('item').value)"/> 
</form>


<script>
function setvalue(){
dropval=document.getElementsByName("selection")[0];
maindropval=dropval.value;
} 
function getstring(x){
    //link="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="+x+"*)?show=sku,name,regularPrice&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";
    //link2= "http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name=ipad|shortDescription=32gb*)?show=sku,name,shortDescription&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";
    link1="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="+x+"*)?show=sku,name,regularPrice,shortDescription&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";  
    link2="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(categoryPath.id="+maindropval+"&name="+x+"*)?show=sku,name,shortDescription,regularPrice,&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";
    if(maindropval=='default'){ 
    alert("worked");
        window.open(link1);}    
    else{
        window.open(link2);}


}
function getresult(value){
link="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name="+x+"*)?show=sku,name,rating,regularPrice&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";
alert("step 2 completed");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please read the [faq]. It would also be nice if you reviewed the [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page. Long blocks of code are difficult to read, and are better presented as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Do you see any errors? I'm guessing you might have a scope issue with maindropval.

Comment: if fone guys just solve it.. I realized that the onselect function does't run till the dropbox has been toggled so I just set an initial value as "default" and it ran from there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it's not working is that the variable `maindropval` is only set when you change the selection in the dropdown.

To get the value `"default"` in the variable, you have to select something other than the first item in the dropdown, and then change back to the first item again.

Set the initial value of the variable:

```
var maindropval = "default";
```

or run the function when the page has loaded to set the value:

```
window.onload = setvalue;
```

(The second solution would preferrable if the browser remembers the form values from a previous selection. In that case the variable would be set from the remembered value for the dropdown.)

Answer (score 0):

Mike and I had the same thought.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVRfC/)... your issue is the scoping of maindropval.

Comment: Partly solved... Declaring the variable avoids the error that you get because the variable is undefined, but you still always get the message "also worked" unless you select something in the dropdown and then change back to the first item, i.e. if you click the button without changing the dropdown it won't recognise that as the first item being selected.

Comment: You're right, it should read `var maindropval ='default';` (http://jsfiddle.net/DVRfC/1/).